# OpenSSL 1.0.0 Beta 4 for win32?

Tags: openssl, windows

Are there binaries available for this?  I can't find any, only messages on newsgroups that it doesn't compile on win32 from back in November 2009.  (I can't even find binaries for 0.9.8l, only 0.9.8k, for win32.)

Comment: 0.9.8l is now available from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Wait for the final release.